# Cutting edges in a tree to reduce maximum depth of all subtrees

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

My question is perhaps a bit underspecified, but what I would like to do is find an algorithm for efficiently decomposing a tree (via cutting edges) into a set of subtrees such that the maximum depth among subtrees is small. Here is one version of the problem:

**Problem 1:** Given a tree and a number *n*, cut *n* edges of the tree so that maximum depth of subtrees is minimal (among choices of cuts).

[For example, for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQQB.jpg) *[n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQQB.jpg)*[=1 in Graph 1, cut at A. For](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQQB.jpg) *[n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQQB.jpg)*[=2 in Graph 2, cut at B and C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQQB.jpg)

[image]

For *n*=1, with a couple passes through the tree we can store for each node its depth, height, and the height of each of its children. Then for each edge (from a parent to child) the size of the two subtrees created will be (i) the depth of the parent + the maximum height of its other children + 1 and (ii) the height of the child. Then take the max of these two values for each edge, and choose the minimum among edges.

For *n*=2, we can stop at each edge and obtain (i) and (ii), and then for whichever one is larger, run the *n*=1 case. We would be able to save some work because if both subtrees are larger than our current min, we can just skip them. However this type of recurrence seems like it would do poorly for larger *n*.

Another version of the problem might be:

**Problem 2:** Given a tree and a depth *d*, what is the shortest sequence of cuts that will leave each subtree with depth less than or equal to *d*?

If anyone is aware of algorithms about similar problems I'd also be interested in hearing about them. This is really for a practical use case, so I'd also consider just an optimization algorithm that uses a good heuristic for choosing which cuts to make. Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Isn't this the [minimum k-cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut) with just a straight line graph?

Comment: @TFS19 Are either of the answers posted helpful? If not, what more are you looking for?

Comment: @Dave Sorry, got busy with some things. I accepted an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem 2:

- Find the depth of every node using BFS. While doing this, maintain an array of the path to the current node. When at depths greater than d, use this array to associate the current node with the node d back in the array from it (s.t. deletion of the edge into such node would cause the current node to be at depth d).
- Pick any node at max depth. If that depth is > d, then cut the edge into the associated ancestral node d steps back found in the BFS step. Remove all nodes reachable from this ancestral node from consideration.
- Repeat the previous step, stopping once there is no node at depth > d.

Total run time: O(n). The middle step is amortized linear time across the algorithm; each time we hit it, it's linear in the number of nodes being removed from consideration, but each node is removed only once.

For problem 1, we can run binary search on d using the approach outlined above for problem 2. This makes problem one O(n log n).

Comment: For the middle step of the p2 approach, you can sort the nodes by depth and associate each node with its index in the sorted array. Then parse the array from deepest to shallowest, skipping over nodes that have been removed in the middle step. Then the entire approach is O(n log n).

Comment: Since for p1, the sorting step mentioned in the previous comment only needs to be done once, this is also O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2 seems trivial:

- Find the root ( vertex with in-degree 0 )

  - Climb the tree. Set v to current vertex and vd to distance from root

    - IF vd = d AND v not a leaf

      - CUT edge between v and it's parent
      - Restart algorithm for each of the two new trees
  - STOP

Comment: In OP's graph 2 example, say d=2. You'd be cutting the 4 edges below B & C, but cutting just B & C also satisfies d=2.

Comment: @Dave adjusted algorithm to explicitly handle leaves.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation.